# What's Assembly in Activator.CreateInstance("Assembly", ClassName)?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Sorry if this is a very stupid question, but I'm lost ...
I have a solution called **GPSd**. This solution has 3 projects:

-*GPSd.BData.DAO*

-*GPSd.Web.Entities*

-*GPSd.Testes*

Since the latter (GPSd.Testes) is the StartUp project.

I'm trying to call the following line from within Entities:

```
var Dao = Activator.CreateInstance(null, NomeClasseDAO);
```

But I get an error message:

> *Additional information: Could not load the HoldingGrupoDao type from the GPSd.Web.Entities assembly, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken = null.*

**What would be this "Assembly" ????**

[image: One image from project]

Comment: Assembly parameter is the Assembly in which the desired type is defined. So in other words, if your type is in `GPSd.BData.DAO` library ( that's the assembly ) you have to specify that assembly's name as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @m.rogalski ! I change my code line for:

var Dao = Activator.CreateInstance("GPSd.BcoDados.DAO", NomeClasseDAO);

But not work. Now I have "Additional information: Could not load the HoldingGrupoDao type from the GPSd.BcoDados.DAO assembly, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a qualified name: "HoldingGrupoDao" is not. You are missing the namespace information. Pass the full name of the type and it should work fine.

Fire up your debugger and and print out `typeof(HoldingGrupoDao).FullName`, the result of *that* is what you need to pass as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this now. But I see another possible problem. The class HoldingGrupoDao  have a Generic params... It is:  public class HoldingGrupoDao : Dao<HoldingGrupoDto, IHoldingGrupoDto>, IHoldingGrupoDao{}  I need pass this?

Comment: It does not seem to be a generic class though, that makes it easier. See my edit.

Comment: That's it @nvoigt !!! I just put the namespace and works!